DLL load failed while importing _version --- rasterio and gdal
I work on Spyder. I need to import 'rasterio', but I always get this error when trying to import it:
import rasterio
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[2], line 1
    import rasterio

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py:28
    from rasterio._version import gdal_version, get_geos_version, get_proj_version

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _version: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.

I'm on version 1.3.10 of 'rasterio', and 3.6.2 of 'gdal'.
Note: I don't know much about code! Detail every step in your solution if you have one please, thanks!
I desinstalled and reinstalled 'rasterio' and 'gdal', as well as updated them. Still no change.
